# It's possible, create a table without primary key in TypeOrm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

And still managing to do @OneToMany in another entity.

```
export class ProductsOfOrder { 
    @ManyToOne(() => Order, order => order.products)
    order: Order

    @ManyToOne(() => Product)
    product: Product

    @Column({type: 'integer'})
    amount: number
}
```

In the case using the foreign key of order

```
@Entity()
export class Order {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string

    @ManyToOne(() => User)
    user: User

    @OneToMany(() => ProductsOfOrder, productsOfOrder => productsOfOrder.order, {cascade: true})
    products: ProductsOfOrder[]
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ciao, no you can't because its required for entities to have a primary column in terms of ORM because most of ORM operations are heavily rely on entity primary ids.

Answer (score 6):

Ahem, of course, you can create a table without a primary key in TypeORM.

Here's a nice dirty little hack:

1. Add a fake primary column to your model and set the insert, select, and update options to false.

```js
@Entity()
export class EntityWithoutPK {
  /**
  * ! This is a fake attribute
  * This is a workaround for TypeORM's `MissingPrimaryColumnError`
  **/
  @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'uuid', insert: false, select: false, update: false })
  id: never;

  // Other column definitions
}
```

2. Generate a migration file and then delete the primary column part from the generated SQL
3. Set synchronize option to false

```js
@Entity({ synchronize: false })
export class Order
```

4. Run the migration

**Notes**

Before applying a hack, see the following checklist. If you have a "no" for any one of them, create a primary key.

1. You'll only query in groups, i.e. often with where condition with another indexed/FK column
2. Individual entity doesn't make sense, you will never call a method (e.g. save) of individual entity
3. The primary key takes a considerable amount of space for an individual record (e.g., UUID primary key for simple metrics).
4. The entity schema doesn't change often; otherwise, the `synchronize: false` option might cause lots of panic.

For your case, it makes total sense to create a primary key in the order table.

Comment: I dont know why, but is still trying to select the column even "select: false" I have. typeorm 0.3.17.

Comment: Same here, did you found solution?